# How to attach errors to fields when using Knockout and Mapping plugin?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm a Knockout.js newbie, trying to figure things out. I have this model for my users:

```
var UserModel = function(data)
{
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    // Other non-relevant stuff

    this.errors = ko.observableArray();

    this.save = function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: API+'user',
            data: ko.mapping.toJSON(this),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            context: this,
            success: function(data)
            {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
            },
            error: function(jqxhr, status, error)
            {
                if(jqxhr.responseJSON.errors)
                    this.errors(jqxhr.responseJSON.errors);
            },
        });
    };
}
```

When the put fails, `errors` gets populated, at least as far as I can see:

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>

{
  "id": 2,
  "email": "alice@example.com",
  "name": "Alice",
  "roles": "login",
  // Other non-relevant stuff
  "errors": {
    "email": [
      "Invalid email domain."
    ],
    "name": [
      "Cannot be empty."
    ]
  }
}
```

But, with a template as below, how can I display these errors next to each field the errors belong to?

The template I'm using for the user currently looks like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="user-row">
    <tr spellcheck="false">
        <td>
            <div data-key="Name" data-bind="editable: editing, editableValue: name"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div data-key="Email" data-bind="editable: editing, editableValue: email"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div data-key="Roles" data-bind="editable: editing, editableValue: roles"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: save">Save</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

1. How do I bind to the error text when there's no key?
2. How do bind "filtered" by key under each `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `this.errors` declared as observable *array* but according to your JSON response you assign an *object*.

You may find useful the method I use very often to extend the functionality of particular observables and observable arrays. I just extend them with *useful* methods (and/or even computed values)

```
this.errors = ko.observable();

// extend observable with a method that allows to get errors for specified field if they exist
this.errors.get = function(field){
    var errs = this.errors();
    return errs && errs[field] && errs[field].join(";");
};

// further in HTML under every div with editable binding:
<span class="error" data-bind="text: errors.get('email')"></span>
```

Comment: \*facepalm\*, didn't think of the fact that it is an object. In PHP it's an associative array, and thought I could have multiple errors per field as well, but actually I don't. Will try out your extension, which seems very handy, tomorrow. Just the kind of tips I'm after 